# Where are my changes committed to git today?

Tags: git

I have very little knowledge on git. I don't want to think bad. Today I began to push my changes to git and then I wanted to resolve conflicts. So, what I did for today is :

```
git pull origin master               # 1
git commit -m "message"              # 2
git push origin master               # 3

git reset --hard origin/master       # 4  resulted in fatal error.

git add *                            # 5
git commit -a -m "my second commit"  # 6
git fetch origin master              # 7
git merge -s recursive \
            -X theirs origin/master  # 8 resulted in message 'up-to-date'
git pull origin/master               # 9 resulted in message 'up-to-date'
```

After that I noticed that all my changes on local repo are lost !

Is there a way back?

Comment: Try using git reflog, finding the SHA for where your commits went wrong, and resetting back to that.

Comment: Error is : Couldn't reset index file to revision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Getting your work back

Have no fear: your commits aren't gone, just unreferenced!

First, make sure your working copy is clean; that is, the output of `git status` shows that you have no local modifications or staged files. If you do, run `git stash` to keep your changes off to the side while you're working.

Now run:

```
git reflog
```

You'll see a list of the names (sha hashes) and messages of the commits that your current branch has pointed to in the recent past. Look for the name of the commit with the message "message" (or whichever was the last commit before the bad merge). Copy the sha of that commit and point `master` back to that commit with:

```
git reset --hard <sha>
```

Look around your working copy; you should have your work back! If it's still not there, go back to the reflog and walk back through the history until you find the right commit that *does* have your work. Now you can re-merge if necessary and push your work back out to `origin` if you choose.

If you `stashed` your changes at the beginning, get them back with `git stash pop` once you're satisfied with where you are.

## What went wrong

The name `origin/master` refers to a special kind of branch called a *remote tracking branch*. Basically, it's a read-only mirror that's synchronized with the last known state of a branch in another git repository; in this case, the `master` branch in the `origin` remote. But the rules for when it's actually updated are a little tricky.

When you run a fully-specified command like `git pull origin master` or `git fetch origin master`, git will *fetch* the commit on `master` from `origin`, but it stores the commit's name in a special reference called `FETCH_HEAD` rather than updating `origin/master`. To keep your remote tracking branches up to date, just run `git fetch` with no arguments instead.

So, what likely happened is that your `reset` (#4) and your `merge` (#8) were both targetting an older commit on `master`!

## What you want to do

To keep up to date with upstream work:

```
# Update all remote-tracking branches with the lastest changes
git fetch
# Merge them in
git merge origin/master
```

To share your work:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thanks very much! When I do `git status` I receive message - `Your branch is ahead of origin master by 1 commit(use git push to publish your local commits)`. Should I do git push?

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help. I tried two commits - one before today first commit and today first commit itself and it didn't return back my files. I used Eclipse history and managed to retrieve some files. I really need to learn git because I am dangerous.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure that you added and committed the work you're looking for into git?

Comment: Also, this is a good resource for getting a handle on git: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: Thnaks for the book. I visited remote repo on my browser and I did notice my commit today with my message. Unfortunately that commit didn't contain my changes at all. This is so strange because when I did push there was no error.